# drag and drop 'dropped items'

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I am trying to drag and drop some items. I can drag a div over to the drop zone div, and it works fine. However, when i drag another div, i can actually drop it inside the previously dropped div. I do not want this. I want the drop zone to be the only place that can accept a dropped div.

```
    <div class='container-fluid'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-sm-12' style='padding:0px;'>
                <div class='col-sm-6'>
                    <div class='row'>
                        <div class='col-sm-2 drag-example' id='drag-1' 
                            draggable='true' ondragstart='drag(event)'></div>
                        <div class='col-sm-2 drag-example' id='drag-2' 
                            draggable='true' ondragstart='drag(event)'></div>
                        <div class='col-sm-2 drag-example' id='drag-3' 
                            draggable='true' ondragstart='drag(event)'></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='col-sm-6'>
                    <div class='row'>
                        <div class='col-sm-10 drop-example' 
                            ondrop='drop(event)' ondragover='allowDrop(event)' 
                                id='drop-div'></div>
                        </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>


function allowDrop(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev){
    ev.dataTransfer.setData('text', ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData('text');
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [prevent drop inside a child element when drag & dropping with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28203585/prevent-drop-inside-a-child-element-when-drag-dropping-with-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change the drop function and add second parameter.
2. append the element to the second parameter passed to drop function.
3. pass `this` reference in drop function as second parameter

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

// change 1 :: added el
function drop(ev, el) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  // change 2 :: append to el
  el.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
}
```

```css
.drag-example {
  border: 1px Solid Black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.drop-example {
  border: 1px Solid Red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class='drag-example' id='drag-1' draggable='true' ondragstart='drag(event)'></div>
<!-- change 3 :: pass this to drop -->
<div class='drop-example' ondrop='drop(event, this)' ondragover='allowDrop(event)' id='drop-div'></div>
```